# Netflix Feign Content type 'pplication/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign

I'm using [Netflix](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) Feign to make my java http clients, using a client like this:

```
public interface PromocodeClient {


@Headers({
    "Content-Type:" + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, "userIdentifier: {userIdentifier}"
})
@RequestLine("POST /rootpath/{code}/unblock")
Boolean unblock(
    @Param("userIdentifier") String userIdentifier,
    @Param("code") String promocode,
    BookingDTO booking);


static PromocodeClient connect() {
    return Feign.builder()
        .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
        .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
        .target(PromocodeClient.class, Urls.SERVICE_URL.toString());
         //Url.SERVICE_URL = http://localhost:8082/1.0
}
```

I'm getting an strange error

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2016-08-02T07:47:16.208+0000",
  "status" : 415,
  "error" : "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message" : "Content type 'pplication/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
  "path" : "/1.0/rootpath/COD_PROMOCODE/unblock"
} 
}
```

The message says "Content type '***pplication***/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported" but I'm using the `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` of Spring which value is

> application/json;charset=UTF-8

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: Does it work if you put a space after the colon? `"Content-Type: " + ...` (shouldn't be necessary; but the server might do something hacky like finding the `:` and moving along 2 characters to find the start of the value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a space after the colon:

```
"Content-Type: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
              ^ here
```

It is not required by the [HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of [linear whitespace], though a single [space] is preferred.

but it is possible that the server you are talking to isn't actually fully compliant with the HTTP standard, and so does something like:

```
header.substring(header.indexOf(':') + 2)
```

to find the value of the header, which handles the "preferred" case only.